# Is there a way of making "embed pages" with Object-based embeds? (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been looking around for a way to make embed pages with discord.js but all of the tutorials I've seen are for a MessageEmbed. I would like to have some way to react to the embed and have it switch to the next.

This is my original code:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content.toLowerCase() == prefix + "help") {
     const Embed = {
    color: 0x91A6A6,
    title: 'Help Menu. Page 1.',
    author: {
        name: 'KLSB',
        icon_url: bot.user.avatarURL()
    },
    description: '\n How to use KLSB. \n',
    fields: [
        {
            name: '!-help',
            value: 'Opens a help menu.',
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: '!-cat',
            value: 'Grabs a random cat picture from the internet.',
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: '!-dog',
            value: 'Grabs a random dog picture from the internet.',
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: '!-panda',
            value: 'Grabs a random panda picture from the internet.',
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: '!-bird',
            value: 'Grabs a random panda picture from the internet.',
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: '!-meme',
            value: 'Finds a meme from Reddit.',
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: '!-animememe',
            value: 'Finds a anime meme from Reddit.',
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: '!-animalmeme',
            value: 'Finds a animal meme from Reddit.',
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: '!-hug',
            value: "Sends a hug through the internet!",
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: '!-8ball',
            value: "As they say, it sees the future!",
            inline: true,
        },
    ],
};

message.channel.send({ embed: Embed });
 }})
```

If anyone has some examples, please share them with me (and it would help if you could explain what's happening :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The one I'm going to show you uses reaction collectors to control which page to go to. You can modify it accordingly to fit with your pages needs, but this is the basic gist.

I first set up an array called `Pages` that would be what you wrote in the description, you can add additional arrays accordingly for your titles and whatnot. I also have `page` set to one since that's the default page and it will be the counter of which page the user is currently on.

There's multiple steps to show how this works:

1. Create initial embed + send embed (which I see you have already done, but you'll need to modify it accordingly to fit with the `pages` array.
2. Then add the reactions (I chose `:rewind:` and `:fast_forward:`. Note: Do not simply just copy them from the Discord channel, as I have learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66252724/discord-js-discordapi-error-unknown-emoji-reacting-to-an-embed).)
3. Then create two separate filters, one for each `ReactionCollector`. I've labeled mine `isBackwards` and `isForwards` accordingly.
4. Create a `ReactionCollector` for both forwards and backwards.
   I've labeled mine `backwards` and `forwards`
5. Then inside of each event handler, I just shifted the `page` and the descriptions and whatnot, and edited the embed accordingly.

**Note:** The second reaction takes a while to load. I haven't found a function where you can put both embeds at the same time... so it might take a while for the second embed to pop up.

---

Code:

```
//pages is very flexible, as long as you change the array at the top you're set
let pages = ["Page one", "Page two", "Page three", "Page four"];
let page = 1;
if (message.content.startsWith("!embed")) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(0xffffff) //sets color here
        .setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
        .setDescription(pages[page - 1])

    message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {
        msg.react('⏪').then(r => {
            msg.react('⏩');
            //filters
            const isBackwards = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⏪' && user.id === message.author.id;
            const isForwards = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⏩' && user.id === message.author.id;

            const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector(isBackwards);
            const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector(isForwards);

            backwards.on("collect", r => {
                if (page === 1) return;
                page--;
                embed.setDescription(pages[page - 1]);
                embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`);
                msg.edit(embed)
            });

            forwards.on("collect", r => {
                if (page === pages.length) return;
                page++;
                embed.setDescription(pages[page - 1]);
                embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`);
                msg.edit(embed)
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I don't know why.

Comment: Nope, it just wont work. Maybe I'm missing a important API

Comment: No, this shouldn't require any APIs at all. It's all within the `discord.js` module.

Comment: Maybe edit your question now to include your code?

Comment: I made a work-around so I think it's all good now, Thanks for the help though :D